# Is JAVA_HOME variable needed when Java Path is defined in system environment variable?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I've set JAVA path in path variable of system environment but not defined JAVA_HOME variable and still I'm able to execute my JAVA programs, why is it happening, is JAVA_HOME variable not needed when JAVA path is defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Java itself there's no need for such a variable. All it cares about is that the path to its `\bin` folder is on the `PATH`. That is the case when you want to execute Java on your console with just calling `java`.

Otherwise, as @CarlosHeuberger mentioned, you don't even need the path to your java executable in your `PATH` variable if you're calling it by its absolute path.

I think other systems depend on the existence of a variable called `JAVA_HOME`, for example Tomcat or Gradle so that they know where Java lies.

Although there is a benefit of having an explicit `JAVA_HOME` variable. After updating/upgrading your Java version, you only have to point that variable to the new installation folder without touching `PATH`.

Comment: +1, but just a detail: actually "For Java itself" the `PATH` doesn't matter - it can be started using the full path like in `C:\Program files\Java\jre\bin\java.exe`. It is the OS that needs the `PATH`.

Comment: Other applications which use java may require Java_Home to locate java in the system. example Maven which requires Java_Home variable to locate the java.